# Difference between Buildcontext and NavigatorKey.currentState.context

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using Provider as state management and also to keep all my function in it. At first i was using a callback method for me to to navigate thru screen when function in my Provider class succeed.

```
Future login(String email, String password, Function callback) async {
 _isLoading = true;
 notifyListeners();
 bool isSuccess = false;
  try {
   final ApiResponse apiResponse = await authRepo!.login(email, password);
   if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response!.statusCode == 200) {
     isSuccess = true;
     callback(isSuccess, apiResponse.response!.data[Constants.responseMsg]);
   } else {
     callback(isSuccess, apiResponse.error);
   }
 } catch (e) {
   _isLoading = false;
   print('login error: $e');
   notifyListeners();
   rethrow;
 }
 _isLoading = false;
 notifyListeners();
}
```

but then i realized i could just pass the Buildcontext and navigating inside the function itself without using a callback method.

```
Future login(String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
 _isLoading = true;
 notifyListeners();
 try {
   final ApiResponse apiResponse = await authRepo!.login(email, password);
   if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response!.statusCode == 200) {
     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
       MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (BuildContext context) => DashboardScreen(),
         settings: RouteSettings(name: '/Dashboard'),
       ),
     );
   } else {
     GlobalFunction.showToast(apiResponse.error);
   }
 } catch (e) {
   _isLoading = false;
   print('login error: $e');
   notifyListeners();
   rethrow;
 }
 _isLoading = false;
 notifyListeners();
}
```

and then i also realize i could use NavigatorKey.currentState!.context to navigate so i dont need the pass the Buildcontext.

```
Future login(String email, String password) async {
_isLoading = true;
notifyListeners();
try {
  final ApiResponse apiResponse = await authRepo!.login(email, password);
  if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response!.statusCode == 200) {
    BuildContext _context = navigatorKey.currentState!.context;
    Navigator.of(_context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => DashboardScreen(),
        settings: RouteSettings(name: '/Dashboard'),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    GlobalFunction.showToast(apiResponse.error);
  }
} catch (e) {
  _isLoading = false;
  print('login error: $e');
  notifyListeners();
  rethrow;
}
_isLoading = false;
notifyListeners();
}
```

i wonder which one is the better way?

Comment: am using the first one but the 3rd option also look good

Comment: The context is specific to whichever widget it comes from. It might not matter depending on what you're doing, but it will for some things. One example where it would matter is if you use `Provider.of(context)`, since depending on which context you use, the resource you are requesting might not exist.

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes i agree the 3rd option look great and you dont need to create a callback inisde your view class which makes it cleaner in my perspective, but is it really okay to rely on navigatorKey.currentState.context?

Comment: @Abion47 yes, but navigatorKey.currentState.context is also keep updating depending where u called them right? or it isnt?

Comment: I do have some other circumstances to use third option if i don't have a view for dialog to show like error dialog or success messages. Which also for me that you can used both of them 1 and 3

Comment: @geezcake `navigatorKey` is an instance of `GlobalKey`, which means it's a unique key that will only ever refer to a single widget to which it is bound. That means, no, that key will always refer to the same widget no matter where you call it unless you personally reassign it. Another note about option 3, `navigatorKey.currentState` can return null if the widget it is bound to is in the middle of regenerating its state.